# How to integrate instamojo payment gateway with codeigniter rest server?

Tags: rest, codeigniter, payment-gateway, codeigniter-restserver, instamojo

I am trying to integrate Instamojo Payment Gateway **within** Chris Kacerguis’ REST Server.

**Problem:**

The below code:

```
public function instamojotest_post()
{
    $api = new Instamojo\Instamojo(‘abcd1234’, ‘efgh5678’, 'https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/');

    try {
        $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate([

            'amount'    => 100,
            'purpose'   => 'New Product Purchase',
            'buyer_name'    => 'Test User',
            'email' => 'testuser@gmail.com',
            'phone' => '9876543210',
            'redirect_url'  => 'http://www.example.com/products_api/validate_payment'
        ]);

        header('Location: ' . $response['longurl']);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $this->response([
            'success'   => false,
            'message'   => $e->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

is not redirecting to the Instamojo Payment Site and no error is being displayed.

It is working fine and redirecting successfully with vanilla CodeIgniter.

**Questions:**

1) Is it, at all, possible to redirect from within a REST Server Post Method?

2) If the above is possible, then what is wrong with my code?

3) Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

I found many tutorials on the internet but none of them are using REST Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled accross this question while Googling. I was also facing the same issue and here is how I solved it.

Note: This is not exactly a solution but a work-around. Also I admit that this may not be the best solution out there, but it worked for me.

I **returned the payment url from the Rest Server**, and **redirected to the url from within the Rest Client**.

Rest Client Code:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function instamojo_make_payment()
    {
        $url = "http://www.example.com/products_api/instamojotest";
        $params = []; //You will obviously be needing this in real life implementation :)

        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        $response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

        if ($response['success'])
            header('Location: ' . $response['payment_url']);
        else
            $this->load->view('payment_failed_page');
    }
}
```

Rest Server Code:

```
class Products_api extends REST_Controller
{
    public function instamojotest_post()
    {
        $api = new Instamojo\Instamojo('abcd1234', 'efgh5678', 'https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/');

        try {
            $response = $api->paymentRequestCreate([
                //Make sure to pass these data from the Rest Client
                'amount'    => 100,
                'purpose'   => 'New Product Purchase',
                'buyer_name'    => 'Test User',
                'email' => 'testuser@gmail.com',
                'phone' => '9876543210',
                'redirect_url'  => 'http://www.example.com/products_api/validate_payment'
            ]);

            $this->response([
                'success'   => true,
                'payment_url'   => $response['longurl']
            ], 200);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $this->response([
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

While giving this answer I assumed that the Api is open. If it is not, then make sure to pass your credentials when making the curl call.

**Update**

Thanks to @AshwiniChaudhary's comment below, which states that:

> REST APIs are not meant for redirection. REST API returns JSON, XML
>   etc and the receiver takes care of whatever is supposed to be done.

the actual reason behind the fact, "why REST Server is not letting us to perform the redirect", becomes pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I was also thinking of this same technique... God knows why it is not allowed to redirect from the Rest Server...

Comment: @Raja REST APIs are not meant for redirection. REST API returns JSON, XML etc and the receiver takes care of whatever is supposed to be done.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thank you so much for the clarification. Then guess we are proceeding in the right direction, right? :)

Comment: @Raja I am not familiar with CodeIgniter, but yeah the basic idea is correct.